# Can't load github wesite

Tags: github, browser

I can't load github.com through a web browser (Chrome, Firefox). Additionally pinging github.com just times out too. This only happens on my laptop, my desktop on the same network loads github.com just fine. However, through a command line I can do git pull, git log, git commit, etc. I remember having to mess around with some weird settings to get the commands to work, so that's probably what stopped me from loading the website.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @VonC not for the whole network. I might have messed around with the local settings when I was trying to get the command line working.

Comment: Check your `git config -l` for any proxy setting then

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the issue may have been with GitHub itself. If you go to https://www.githubstatus.com/ you can get the real time status for all GitHub services.

It's possible that there was an issue with the website but not the services. Checking githubstatus before tearing your setting apart could help you avoid some headache. (Not sure if your issue was a GitHub outage or not).